# SSL with prestashop using docker installation

Tags: docker, ssl, prestashop, ovh

I have installed certbot on my server, and I installed prestashop usig docker-compose.yml file.
I have configured a domain name 'test.tn' on apache and it works, then I saved an ssl certificate on that domain and it successfully installed.
After adding the certificate, my backoffice work correctly, but the frontoffice is not, it appear without styles. And in the backoffice, I can't activate the ssl even all urls are https. Also, in my database,, the variable SSL_SHOP_ENABLE is set to 0, I try to make it 1 but nothing changed.
Is there a solution ?